# Mysql aes_encrypted data comparison

Tags: mysql, encryption, compare

I want to compare data encrypted with mysql aes_encrypt() against the encrypted data sent from my app

```
MySQL version: 10.2.43-MariaDB
Test data: 'abc'
password: '123'
encrypted data sent from my app: 0x911ff5b9a15aae9b52e7e9fde75315b1
```

The tests table contains one single record and the column varbinary50 contains data encrypted with mysql's aes_encrypt():

```
CREATE TABLE `tests` (
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `varbinary50` varbinary(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tests`
--

INSERT INTO `tests` (`test_id`, `varbinary50`) VALUES
(6, 0x911ff5b9a15aae9b52e7e9fde75315b1);
```

Since varbinary50 contains exactly the value '0x911ff5b9a15aae9b52e7e9fde75315b1', I expect following query to return 1; instead it's 0.

```
select varbinary50='0x911ff5b9a15aae9b52e7e9fde75315b1' from tests
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong?    TIA

Answer (score 1):

Solution: apply hex to varbinary50 and remove "0x" prefix from the data

```
  select lower(hex(varbinary50))='911ff5b9a15aae9b52e7e9fde75315b1' from tests
```

Comment: Yeah, I was already looking at how the 0x value would be handled and found some issues, but you already solved it. Glad because I'm not necessarily a DB expert. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours.